# opening a .css file throws me an error

Tags: text, css

Opening this file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W47IfvZ_FiGhZgwnUlmgQHA5_4FFZvRc/view gives me this error and it won't let me edit it:

> The file you opened contains some invalid characters. Continuing to edit this file may corrupt the document.
> You can also choose any other character encoding and try again.

It happens to me both with the Ubuntu text editor and with Netbeans. In Windows it opens without problems in any editor.

Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Yep. You've got a corrupted CSS file there. At the bottom it says that it was extracted with a ZIP application. You may want to confirm the source `.zip` and try to re-extract. If you bought this as part of a theme, consider downloading a fresh copy of the data.

Comment: Have you tried to open that file in firefox, if still, it couldn't be opened trie with chrome. Yes of course as @matigo said it might be corrupted.

Comment: in windows it opens without problems with any editor.

Comment: I didn't have any problem opening it, either, which is why I could see lots of invalid characters and the message at the bottom of the file. If you are able to open the file flawlessly – without erroneous characters – in Windows, then perhaps you should open it there, save it with a proper UTF-8 unicode encoding, and then use the new file on non-Windows systems 

Comment: although in windows it opens the file without problems, I have verified that it contains invalid characters for a css file. And it is not extrated from a .zip file. It is downloaded directly from a prestashop insallation in a server.